# Azure DB prevent from Scaling up without permission

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server

I've been on the cheapest Azure SQL DB plan (Basic + 5 DTUs) for about 10 months. Bills were low such as usage. I check the bill once in a while after checking my July one was really confused as it went up by 5 times. I went to the resource manager and found that the DB was scaled up by moving it to Standard belt + DTUs increased to 15 or so. I didn't ask for it, nor there was a reason to do that as it's still the same pet project which is still used only by me.

Could anyone confirm if it's a "normal" practice to upgrade my plans without my permission? In case if it dynamically scales up - how do I turn it off?

Comment: no, this doesn't happen on its own.

Comment: @4c74356b41 so it must have been initiated by someone? I'm the only user of it and definitely didn't ask for it. Why would I?

Comment: You can file a ticket (New Support Request ) for clear clarification,that when/who is the reason behind the ScaleUp.It's the best way to get clarify.I don't think it would be Auto-Scale Up by Azure itself.

Comment: What does the Activity log of your database say? It will tell you who initiated the upgrade as well as when it was initiated.